# "/dev" folder permissions for a container running in Kubernetes

Tags: linux, kubernetes, containers, filesystems

When creating a Kubernetes pod using the following yaml -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
  labels:
    app: busybox
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: ubuntu
    image: ubuntu:latest
    # Just spin & wait forever
    command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
    args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]
    securityContext:
      readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
```

I was supposed to get a Read-Only filesystem container.
But something that I have noticed is that even with this configuration there are still writable (and executable) folders in the filesystem -

```
root@busybox:/# mount | grep -v noexec | grep -v ro
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=65536k,mode=755)
/dev/vda1 on /dev/termination-log type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/vda1 on /etc/hosts type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

I was wondering if it's possible to make `/dev` to be `ro` too? and also, is it possible to make it `noexec`? or there is some reason that `/dev` should be writable and executable?

Comment: Mounting /dev as read-only and/or noexec can affect the working of the pod depending on the applications running inside the container and their dependencies on the devices in /dev.
For example, if an application running inside the container needs to access a device in /dev for its functionality, mounting /dev as read-only  may cause the application to fail or behave unexpectedly.

Comment: In general, it's recommended to leave /dev as writable and executable unless you have a specific reason to change it. If you need to restrict access to certain devices in /dev, you can use Kubernetes SecurityContexts to limit the access of containers to specific devices or device types.